# Definition - Simple random sample

Tags: sample

In a textbook of mine I detected the follow definition of a random sample:

"Every possible sample of size n has the same probability of being selected"

However, I also already saw some definitions that are formulated like the following:

"Every unit has the same probability of being selected"

Therefore, I wanted to know, whether these two definitions are equivalent.

Comment: The first definition needs first a definition of "sample" to make sense.

Comment: The second is not a correct definition.  For instance, consider samples of size $2$ from the set $\{0,1,2,3\}$ and suppose the samples $\{0,1\},$ and $\{2,3\}$ have equal chances of $1/2$ to be your sample.  Each unit has probability $1/2$ of being selected, *but there is no chance that $1$ and $2$ occur in the same sample.*